# Google Analytics API returns Null for channel sources on SOME sites

Tags: php, api, google-analytics

I've built a small application (written in PHP and just being run locally) to pull Google Analytics results each month and display certain metrics/dimensions nicely using ChartJS which then gets saved as a PDF and emailed off to the clients.

However, as of last month, I cannot get the API to return any data for acquisition channels for 2 sites in particular - all the other sites are totally fine.

It just so happens that these 2 sites see upwards of tens of thousands of unique visits each month - this is the only factor I can see as to why these 2 may be different from the rest.

I'm able to pull all the other metrics for these sites successfully, and can view channel acquisitios if I manually visit the Google Analytics site, but the API just won't return anything.

No errors, no warnings, just an empty return value.

Nothing has changed in the last few months with the code on my end, and everything is working on other sites, just not these 2 so I know the code is working. And it's specifically only channel acquisition which are affected.

I've tried setting the max return value without success also.

Google reports no updates to the API which would cause this.

Any help or advice very much appreciated!